# PHP library to design connections between things?

Tags: library, php

I'm currently looking to see if there is any library in PHP which can do the following ?

[image]

Comment: Look into Graphvzi - you can't beat it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176172/drawing-a-graph-with-graphviz-in-php